# CakePHP Redirect After post with Target URL

Tags: cakephp

I have written a CakePHP application and am struggling with the following problem:

1. I created an Add view plus corresponding controller function,
   which after a POST creates an additional note record in a notes
   table for a linked master customer record.
2. After the post I am
   redirecting back to the controller "Customer" with the action
   'view'.
3. After a user had added a note, CakePHP properly shows
   then the customer 'view' view including the added record note.
4. HOWEVER, the URL in the browser still is .../notes/add/... which
   creates further routing problems: if then a user presses reload, he
   would expect to see the customer view reloaded, but it will show the
   add notes view.

How can I force a redirect after a POST with updated URL?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand everythings (because of my poor english), but you can use Controller::redirect to force a redirect at the end of a controller.

[Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3aredirect)